# Read and write large file with python

Tags: python, file, text, io, python-3.5

I have a large `.txt` file with more than 24,000,000 lines. Now I'd like to do a word count, that is, count each word and its corresponding occurrence and record them to a new file. Here is the code I tried to run:

```
import gensim
class Corpus(gensim.corpora.TextCorpus): 
    def count_tokens(self):
        word_count = 0
        for text in self.get_texts():
            word_count += len(text)
        return word_count
    def get_texts(self): 
        for filename in self.input: 
            yield open(filename).read().split()

def main():
    corpus = Corpus(['somefile.txt'])
    word_count = corpus.count_tokens()
    text = open('somefile.txt').read().split()
    with open('path_to_output', 'w') as f:
        for word, _ in corpus.dictionary.token2id.items():
            num_occur = text.count(word)
            f.write('%s %d\n' % (word, num_occur))

if __name__  == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the server hang... I wonder if there is other sufficient way to do so or any improvement I can make? How do you read and write really large file with python?

Comment: use a tokenizer like system - parse char char, and check for matches. when ambiguous, proceed to look into next chars to decide whether there is a continuation

Comment: `open(filename).read().split()` reads the file fully then creates a tokenized version: twice the memory at the same time. Uriel method is probably the correct one if you just need to count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `get_texts()` method is reading one entire file in memory at a time. It's fine for corpora with lots of small files, but if you have one enormous file, you need to read it line by line.

```
from collections import Counter
wordcounts = Counter()

with open("file.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        wordcounts.update(line.split())
```

Comment: what would happen if the file is just a long list of words? with a file big enough, that would still stay a problem

Comment: OMG, this method can finish in several minutes! Save my day! Thanks!

Comment: @Uriel, one word per line works the same. There would only be a problem if there are no newlines in the file. For such cases you'd need to read blocks of bytes, and repair broken words and even broken multi-byte characters at the edges. Obviously it would be easier to plug in a library that can do this. But clearly this is a _text_ file, i.e. newlines, so no need to go there.

Comment: @alexis that's what I meant, a list separated by spaces. but judging by OP's comment, that's not the case. good answer in that case.

Comment: For a file without newlines, the nltk's corpus readers are backed by a "stream reader" that does what I described. Gensim probably does too (I don't use it), but the OP bypassed its file i/o. Anyway the OP's question is about a file with more than 24 million **lines**.

Comment: @user5779223, since my answer solved your problem, please "accept" it to mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has many issues:

- it reads the file in memory, then splits the words, so it doubles (or triples) the memory size
- it does that twice, first to count the number of words, then to count the occurrences of each word

I've created a simple example, without your objects and all, using `collections.Counter` on several files. `text_file_list` holds the list of the file paths.

```
import collections

c = collections.Counter()
for text_file in text_file_list:
   with open(text_file) as f:
       c.update(word for line in f for word in line.split())
```

that loops on the files, and updates the specialized `Counter` dictionary for each file. Files are read line by line, never completely. So it takes some time, but not too much memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this :

```
words = {}
with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as textf:
    for line in textf.readlines():
        for word in line.split():
            words[word] = words.getdefault(word, 0) + 1
```

Not very pythonic but it's the idea

Comment: This won't help, it still reads the entire file in memory at once.

Comment: but replacing `for line in textf.readlines():` by `for line in textf:` should be better. It would only read 1 line at a time, and no other changes are needed.

Comment: also using `collections.Counter` would be better.